# Comparing List of Map items in Java

Tags: java, list, foreach, hashmap, iterator

I have a function wherein i need to check if data matches in two lists.
The list is a linkedlist of type `Map <String, Object>`.  How should I iterate to compare each item in map for both the list in the most efficient manner ?

Right now I am trying to do something like this :

```
public boolean compare(List<Map<String, Object>> A,
            List<Map<String, Object>> B) {
        //Code for iteration 
        boolean result = false;
        if(A.size() == B.size()) {    
            int count = 0;
            for(Map<String, Object> a : A)
            {
                for(Map<String, Object> b : B)
                {
                    if (a.get('aID') == b.get('aID'))
                        count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == A.size()) {
                result = true;
            }
        }    
        else {
            //Data reconciliation failed :: Data size mismatch
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But this is an inefficient approach as each item in A is compared with every item in B.

Is there a better approach ?

Comment: For basic `Java` implementations, such as `LinkedList`, the `equals(Object other)` method should properly do what you want.

Comment: And likewise, for Object don't use ==, use Object.equals().

Comment: The Lists are different.. They are lists of row maps of some table. The data is similar in two tables but table structure is different and hence I am doing a reconciliation of data after a backfill which requires each entry to be compared. They are not same objects.

Comment: A is a list of rows of table A and B is a list of rows of table B. They have the same data but table structure is different and hence comparison on each row is required for validation.

Comment: There is a compiler error here, `a` is not within the scope where it is defined. `if(count == a.size()) { result = true; }`, therefore your code should not have compiled anyways. Aka, fix your indentation and make sure your brackets match. Also string literals are represented with double quotes not single quotes

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280088/how-to-compare-two-list-of-map-to-identify-the-matching-and-non-matching-records/64816458#64816458

Answer (score 2):

You could loop over the List one time and compare Maps in each list. This would cut your Big-O runtime in half -- assumes that the Maps are in the proper order (i.e., via LinkedList).

```
public boolean compare(List<Map<String, Object>> A, List<Map<String, Object>> B) {
    // check size first
    if (A.size() == B.size()) {
      // if the Maps are abstracted into a POJO you could implement Comparator on that POJO.  In the meantime you can sort manually
      // sort A
      Collections.sort(A, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
        public int compare(final Map<String, String> o1, final Map<String, String> o2) {
            // optionally, you could use any method of sorting here... single field like an ID, multiple fields compared, sums, etc.
            return o1.get("field").compareTo(o2.get("field"));
        }
    });

      // sort B
      Collections.sort(B, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
        public int compare(final Map<String, String> o1, final Map<String, String> o2) {
            return o1.get("field").compareTo(o2.get("field"));
        }
    });


        for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            // get map from A & B
            Map<String, Object> aMap = A.get(i);
            Map<String, Object> bMap = B.get(i);

            // check equality of Maps
            if (!aMap.equals(bMap)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Data reconciliation failed :: Data size mismatch
        return false;
    }

    // if we get here then all was good
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But when we retrieve data from two different tables into these lists, they are not in a specific order. so we cant check linearly. The row containing common data can be present in 1st position in list A but  n-1 or n-2 or any other position in list B. So have to check via key comparison.

Comment: Hmm... you could sort the Lists when they come into the compare method.  I don't know specifics in your Maps but will update the example to illustrate...

Comment: select as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is mate...
The most efficient way to compare two List of Map to identify the matching and non matching records with multiple filter predicates in Java8 Streams is:

```
List<Map<String,String>> unMatchedRecords = dbRecords.parallelStream().filter(searchData ->
                inputRecords.parallelStream().noneMatch( inputMap ->
                        searchData.entrySet().stream().noneMatch(value ->
                                inputMap.entrySet().stream().noneMatch(value1 ->
                                        (value1.getKey().equals(value.getKey()) &&
                                                value1.getValue().equals(value.getValue()))))
                )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note:

If <Map<String,String> used above is <Map<Object,Object> instead, don't forget to apply .toString() for .getKey() and value.getKey().

The unmatched records thus obtained, could be easily subtracted from either of the list (i.e., dbRecords or inputRecords) to retrieve the match results and the operation is swift.

Cheers,

Shubham Chauhan