# How to compare Two List of Map to identify the matching and non matching records with multiple filter predicates in Java8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8

Requirement is to get all the matching and non matching records from the List of Map using multiple matching criteria using the streams. i.e Instead of having a single filter to compare only "Email", required to compare two list for matching records with multiple filter predicate for comparing Email and Id both.

List1:

```
[{"Email","naveen@domain.com", "Id": "A1"}, 
 {"Email":"test@domain.com","id":"A2"}]
```

List2:

```
[{"Email","naveen@domain.com", "Id": "A1"}, 
 {"Email":"test@domain.com","id":"A2"}, 
 {"Email":"test1@domain.com","id":"B1"}]
```

Using streams I'm able to find the matching and non matching records using Single filter predicate on Email:
Matching Records :

```
[{"Email","naveen@domain.com", "Id": "A1"}, 
 {"Email":"test@domain.com","id":"A2"}]
```

Non Matching Records :

```
[{"Email":"test1@domain.com","id":"B1"}]]
```

Is there a way to compare both Email and Id comparison instead of just Email

```
dbRecords.parallelStream().filter(searchData ->
                inputRecords.parallelStream().anyMatch(inputMap ->
                    searchData.get("Email").equals(inputMap.get("Email")))).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
public class ListFiltersToGetMatchingRecords {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Map<String, Object>> dbRecords = createDbRecords();
        List<Map<String, Object>> inputRecords = createInputRecords();

        List<Map<String,Object>> matchinRecords = dbRecords.parallelStream().filter(searchData ->
                inputRecords.parallelStream().anyMatch(inputMap ->
                    searchData.get("Email").equals(inputMap.get("Email")))).
                collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Map<String,Object>> notMatchinRecords = inputRecords.parallelStream().filter(searchData ->
                dbRecords.parallelStream().noneMatch( inputMap ->
                        searchData.get("Email").equals(inputMap.get("Email"))
                )).collect(Collectors.toList());

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Matching Records: " + matchinRecords.size());
        matchinRecords.forEach(record -> {
            System.out.println(record.get("Email"));
        });

        System.out.println("Non Matching Records" + notMatchinRecords.size());
        notMatchinRecords.forEach(record -> {
            System.out.println(record.get("Email"));
        });
        System.out.println("Non Matching Records" + notMatchinRecords.size());
        System.out.println("Matching Records: " + matchinRecords.size());
        System.out.println("TotalTImeTaken =" + ((endTime-startTime) /1000) + "sec");
    }

    private static List<Map<String, Object>> createDbRecords() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> dbRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0; i< 100; i+=2) {
            Map<String, Object> dbRecord = new HashMap<>();
            dbRecord.put("Email","naveen" + i +"@gmail.com");
            dbRecord.put("Id", "ID" + i);
            dbRecords.add(dbRecord);
        }
        return dbRecords;
    }

    private static List<Map<String, Object>> createInputRecords() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> dbRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0; i< 100; i++) {
            Map<String, Object> dbRecord = new HashMap<>();
            dbRecord.put("Email", "naveen" + i +"@gmail.com");
            dbRecord.put("ID", "ID" + i);
            dbRecords.add(dbRecord);
        }
        return dbRecords;
    }
}
```

Comment: `... anyMatch(inputMap -> searchData.get("Email").equals(inputMap.get("Email")) && searchData.get("Id").equals(inputMap.get("Id")))`?

Comment: `id` or `Id` or `ID` ? there i all of the 3 in your post

Comment: See also: [How to apply multiple Filters on Java Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187038/how-to-apply-multiple-filters-on-java-stream)

Comment: Using multiple filters is not a feasible option as the comparison keys/fields are dynamic, means these keys changes at runtime dynamically. Either "Email" or "Id" or  "Email" and "Id" both has to be used depending the fields exist in the list. In this case how to apply multiple filters assuming this comparison keys I get is a list of strings List<String>.

Answer (score 5):

If you care for performance, you should not combine a linear search with another linear search; with the resulting time complexity can’t be fixed with parallel processing when the lists get large.

You should built a data structure which allows efficient lookups first:

```
Map<List<?>,Map<String, Object>> inputKeys = inputRecords.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        m -> Arrays.asList(m.get("ID"),m.get("Email")),
        m -> m,
        (a,b) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate "+a+" and "+b); },
        LinkedHashMap::new));

List<Map<String,Object>> matchinRecords = dbRecords.stream()
    .filter(m -> inputKeys.containsKey(Arrays.asList(m.get("ID"),m.get("Email"))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

matchinRecords.forEach(m -> inputKeys.remove(Arrays.asList(m.get("ID"),m.get("Email"))));
List<Map<String,Object>> notMatchinRecords = new ArrayList<>(inputKeys.values());
```

This solution will keep the identity of the `Map`s.

If you are only interested in the values associated with the `"Email"` key, it would be much simpler:

```
Map<Object,Object> notMatchinRecords = inputRecords.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        m -> m.get("ID"),
        m -> m.get("Email"),
        (a,b) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate"); },
        LinkedHashMap::new));

Object notPresent = new Object();
Map<Object,Object> matchinRecords = dbRecords.stream()
    .filter(m -> notMatchinRecords.getOrDefault(m.get("ID"), notPresent)
                                  .equals(m.get("Email")))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        m -> m.get("ID"),
        m -> m.get("Email"),
        (a,b) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate"); },
        LinkedHashMap::new));

notMatchinRecords.keySet().removeAll(matchinRecords.keySet());

System.out.println("Matching Records: " + matchinRecords.size());
matchinRecords.forEach((id,email) -> System.out.println(email));

System.out.println("Non Matching Records" + notMatchinRecords.size());
notMatchinRecords.forEach((id,email) -> System.out.println(email));
```

---

The first variant can get extended to support more/other map entries easily:

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("ID", "Email");

Function<Map<String,Object>,List<?>> getKey
    = m -> keys.stream().map(m::get).collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<List<?>,Map<String, Object>> inputKeys = inputRecords.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        getKey,
        m -> m,
        (a,b) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate "+a+" and "+b); },
        LinkedHashMap::new));

List<Map<String,Object>> matchinRecords = dbRecords.stream()
    .filter(m -> inputKeys.containsKey(getKey.apply(m)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

matchinRecords.forEach(m -> inputKeys.remove(getKey.apply(m)));
List<Map<String,Object>> notMatchinRecords = new ArrayList<>(inputKeys.values());
```

Comment: the last version is insane :| you are using `Function<Map<String,Object>,List<?>>` as a Key in a Map... that's something I have not seen until now, this will use hashCode/equals of `Object`?

Comment: @Eugene no, no, this function *provides* the key for the map. The key itself is the `List`, which has appropriate `equals` and `hashCode`. It’s the function that you would normally provide as the first argument to `toMap` directly, but here, the function is reused in the subsequent steps to ensure consistency (no code duplication, no potential inconsistency).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a condition in the comparison

```
dbRecords.parallelStream().filter(searchData -> 
                  inputRecords.parallelStream().anyMatch(inputMap ->
                                     searchData.get("Email").equals(inputMap.get("Email"))
                                     && searchData.get("id").equals(inputMap.get("id"))))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

- Add the same in the `noneMatch()`.
- Compute the average time using `System.nanoTime()`, it's more accurate
- Try with and without `.parallelStream()` (just `.stream()`) because not sure it helps you)

Answer (score 1):

## Here it is mate...

#### The most efficient way to compare two List of Map to identify the matching and non matching records with multiple filter predicates in Java8 Streams is:

```
List<Map<String,String>> unMatchedRecords = dbRecords.parallelStream().filter(searchData ->
                inputRecords.parallelStream().noneMatch( inputMap ->
                        searchData.entrySet().stream().noneMatch(value ->
                                inputMap.entrySet().stream().noneMatch(value1 ->
                                        (value1.getKey().equals(value.getKey()) &&
                                                value1.getValue().equals(value.getValue()))))
                )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note:**

1. If <Map<String,String> used above is <Map<Object,Object> instead, don't forget to apply .toString() for .getKey() and value.getKey().
2. The unmatched records thus obtained, could be easily subtracted from either of the list (i.e., dbRecords or inputRecords) to retrieve the match results and the operation is swift.

Cheers,

Shubham Chauhan

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `&&` inside `anyMatch`:

```
anyMatch(inputMap -> searchData.get("Email").equals(inputMap.get("Email")) 
                     && searchData.get("Id").equals(inputMap.get("Id")))
```

And I doubt you actually need `parallelStream`, you do need `System.nanoTime` on the other hand instead of `currentTimeMillis`

Comment: Since this combination of two linear searches has quadratic time complexity, it is imaginable that the OP gets into the region where parallel execution makes a difference with sufficiently large lists, however, it’s also easy to get into regions where even that won’t fix the poor performance. A better solution, i.e. hashing from ID to record, would solve that and bring it back into regions where parallel processing is obsolete.

Comment: @Holger *hashing from ID to record*, not entirely sure I understand this

Comment: Built a `Map` from ID to whatever data structure you like. It looks like a `Map` from ID to E-Mail address would be sufficient, but perhaps, these maps can contain other items which should be retained, in that case, map from ID to map.

Comment: Email & Id comparison comparison is works only when Email and Id is the comparison candidate. But what if this comparison has to happen dynamically that is for example ["Email","Id", "OtherFieldName"], the comparison fields changes dynamically, if that is the case then in runtime how to generated the filter condition using that list of fields?

Comment: @NaveenKumarDC I think you can reduce your Strings to a single predicate via `Stream.of("Email", "Id", "OtherFieldName")
                .map(x -> (Predicate<Map<String, String>>) (Map<String, String> inputMap) -> searchData.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase(inputMap.get(x)))
                .reduce(Predicate::and)
                .orElse(x -> false);` for example